# About the "dot product" in the material derivative

Tags: inner-products, tensors, fluid-dynamics

Recently the material derivative was mentioned in my fluid dynamics class. The definition given is
$$\operatorname{MD}=\partial_t +\mathbf{u}~\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\nabla$$
Where of course $\nabla$ is taken to be the covariant derivative using the Levi Civita connection. However, I'm a little confused as to what to do with that dot product in the general setting, especially when dealing with higher order tensors in arbitrary coordinate systems. Let's say I am using some arbitrary coordinate system $\{x_i\}$ with corresponding metric tensor $\mathbf{g}$. Now suppose I have some $(r,s)$ tensor $\mathbf{T}$. I want to know what the components of that "dot product" will be. Do I just do

### $$(\mathbf{u}~\boldsymbol{\cdot}\nabla\mathbf{T})^{i_1,...,i_r}_{j_1,...,j_s}=g_{\mu\nu}u^\mu T^{i_1,...,i_r}_{j_1,...,j_s~;~\nu}$$

Or is it something else completely? My professor really didn't talk much about the general case for higher order tensors, nor did he talk about what to do in an arbitrary coordinate system - he just gave formulas for the material derivative of scalars/vectors in the standard and cylindrical coordinate cases.

Also, if the components of $\mathbf{u}$ are given with respect to a *normalized* basis, e.g in plane polars $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r=\cos\theta \mathbf{e}_x+\sin\theta\mathbf{e}_y$, $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_\theta=-\sin\theta\mathbf{e}_x+\cos\theta\mathbf{e}_y$ do I need to *unnormalize* them before I try to take the dot product? I would really like some clarification on this matter.

Thanks.

Comment: The "dot product" just means you're looking at the covariant derivative along the vector field $\mathbf{u}$, so $(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla) T$ means $\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}T$. From here if $T$ is an $(r,s)$ tensor field then $\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}T$ is again an $(r,s)$ tensor field. If you want to calculate components, then you're going to end up with a lot of $\Gamma$ terms (some plus some minus). You're not taking an inner product so $g_{\mu\nu}$ doesn't appear anywhere (other than implicitly in the definition of the $\Gamma$'s).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for the reply! Would I just do $$(\mathbf{u}~\boldsymbol{\cdot}\nabla\mathbf{T})^{i_1,...,i_r}_{j_1,...,j_s}=u^k T^{i_1,...,i_r}_{j_1,...,j_s~;~k}$$ in that case?

Comment: Yes, that's right (I orignally didn't see the semicolon :) and thought you just meant a partial derivative). We have $(u\cdot \nabla T)^{I}_J = u^k (\nabla_kT)^I_J = u^k T^I_{J;k}$ (where I just wrote $I,J$ for short).